# VSCode - where can I find the color codes used in default theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCODE 1.46.1.

My OS is Linux Mint 19.3

I am using the default `Default Light+` theme.

I want see which colors it has used in the status bar. Where can I find the files which has the color codes of `Default Light+`.

I have search both `~/.vscode` & `~/.config/Code` for files where text containing `statusBar.background`, but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply go to the source code at [light_plus.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/7a5bca9fafbbb23de289179be95e9c4832540c02/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/light_plus.json)

Or in the case of linux, usually is stored at: `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/light_plus.json`

```sh
cd /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/
```

Will put you in the folder where all the default themes are. but we warned - future updates might overwrites those files.

**Important note**: there's an hierarchy: light_plus -> light_vs -> light_defaults -> etc. common which is the base is in the code [theme.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/common/theme.ts#L350), so if you can't find a setting, look at the parent.

Comment: Where is the file in my computer?

Comment: I wanted to see the value of `statusBar.noFolderBackground`, `statusBar.background` & `statusBar.debuggingBackground`. The values are not there.

Comment: look at `light_defaults.json`, if not there - go for the source for common:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/common/theme.ts#L350

Comment: There colors are not there in the format I wanted, however, it worked.

Comment: there's an hierarchy: light_plus -> light_vs -> light_defaults -> common (in the code)

Comment: Please add the comment part to the main answer so that others don't miss it.

Answer (score 0):

There are in `resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes` of you vscode install

Find which by using `which code` in your terminal